# beginner whats wrong with my method

Tags: java, methods

```
public class assignment6part3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int q = 0;
        for ( int count=1; count <= 10000; count++) {
            if (Prime(count)) {
                q = q + 1;

            } 
        }
        System.out.println("It comes out " + q + " times.");
    }


    public static boolean Prime(int n) {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the number of prime numbers between 0 and 10000, but when I run this, it says there are 0 prime numbers. What part of the code is causing this error?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code and inspecting the state of your variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your function `Prime` your `for` loop runs like ::
`for(int i = 1; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++)`, starting from `i = 1` and every number is divisible by `1` and hence `0` prime numbers.. :P

Initialization condition for `i` shall be `i = 2`

Other things you might consider changing ::

`for (int i = 1; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++)` shall be changed to

`for (int i = 1; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++)`

NOTE :: A more optimal way to find Primes would be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Oh, I thought that even though I started at 1, then i would go up anyways. Thanks!

Comment: It should be noted that a more efficient way of doing this would be to restructure the `Prime()` method to take a number, and have it check on each loop if the number is prime. This way you aren't doing multiple for loops in each other. But, I digress.

Comment: It says that 1254 prime numbers come out but the answer is supposed to be 1229. Why is that?

Comment: What are the divisors of `25`? Does your code give the correct answer for this case?

Comment: How about `i <=Math.sqrt(n);` instead?

Comment: @David : I didn't exactly understand what you were trying to say.. :\ A more optimal way to finding primes?

Comment: @user007 No no, I misread his code. For some reason I thought he was doing it in O(n^2) time, and that there could be a faster way. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

The code is returning `false` before it actually checks the numbers, because every number is divisible by 1. Also, in some cases such as 25 and 49, the factors are not less than the square root. Try this:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
```